# Cloud code function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, java, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm not sure why this cloud code function appears to be being called 5 times every time the function is called from the client.

Cloud Code -

```
Parse.Cloud.define('PushTest', function(request, response){
console.log('PushTest called');
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.Username);
query.equalTo("device_type","main");

Parse.Push.send({
        where: query,
        data: {
            alert: "This is a test"
        }
    }, {
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function() {
        //push was succesful
        console.log('Push Success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //handle error
        console.log('Push failure');
    }

    });
});
```

Client code -

```
        String username = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("Username", username);
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("PushTest", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
            public void done(Object obj, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Parse cloud called");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Parse cloud not called");
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Every time I call the function from the client, I receive five push notifications rather than just one. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe client retry it 4(default maxRetries) times due to some error (timeout?)

To check is this case, set the log level (less than info) and see the log in sdk.
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/Parse.html#setLogLevel(int)

The log is set about line 230.

PLog.i("com.parse.ParseRequest", "Request failed. Waiting " + delay              + " milliseconds before attempt #" + (attemptsMade + 1));

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseRequest.java

If this log shows, u should try to avoid the error.

For a fast solution may call it by rest api, which will not auto retry.
(not sure that the retry times can be changed outside the sdk)

If the log not shown, try to see the request from client.

To do this, u can use charles-proxy, set your device proxy to your computer.

To see the detail(SSL), download credential on your device and set SSL proxy-setting on computer.

After that you can see how many requests send from your device.

And then try to find out where the problem is.